# Get Current Delimiter Used by Scanner Class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is it possible to get the *current* delimiter a Scanner is using, when that delimiter is a regular expression? For example I have this code:

```java
        String dictionary = "computer: A computer is an electronic machine that can store\n"
                          + "          and deal with large amounts of information.\n"
                          + "computer-aided: done or improved by computer\n"; 
        Scanner src = new Scanner(dictionary);
        String delimiterRegex = "^(.+?:)"; // <-- Matches a new term
        Pattern delimiterPattern = Pattern.compile(delimiterRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        src.useDelimiter(delimiterPattern);
        String definition = "";
        String term = "";

        while(src.hasNext())
        {
            definition = src.next();
            term = ???????; // <--- The term is the current delimiter match
        }
```

This is a very easy way to get all of the definitions, if only I could also get the term.

Comment: You can only get back the `Pattern` (using `getDelmiter()`) that's being used to match delimiters.  But there doesn't appear to be any way to get the actual delimiting text when reading a token.  I could be wrong; [here's the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), judge for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Instead of trying to get the scanner's *matched* delimiter, which is an implementation detail, you should rewrite the delimiter regex so that `next` returns what you want.

For example:

```
// this matches both the zero-width string before the term, and the zero-width string after the colon
String delimiterRegex = "^(?=.+?:)|(?<=:)";
Pattern delimiterPattern = Pattern.compile(delimiterRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
src.useDelimiter(delimiterPattern);
String definition = "";
String term = "";

while(src.hasNext())
{
    term = src.next(); // read the term first!
    definition = src.next();
}
```

Alternatively, just use a single regex to do this. I was able to come up with:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:\r\n]+?:)([\\s\\S]+?)(?=^[^:\r\n]+?:|\\z)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(dictionary);
while (m.find()) {
    String term = m.group(1);
    String definition = m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution puts the problem in the right light. The delimiters for this dictionary should be the boundaries before and after the term - the beginning of the line with a new term (^), or the boundary immediately following the colon. Unfortunately this (and the other) solution fall apart if there is a colon in the definition. A definition of 'time' might include '00:00:00' for example. This regex works perfectly however "^(?=\\w.+?:)|(?<=^\\S+:)" if we assume the term has no whitespace, which I can't. But I can't get it to work otherwise. Still working on it.

Comment: @timothyadam If the term can have `:`, your original regex, `(.+?:)` wouldn't work either, would it?

Comment: True if the colon appeared on anything other than the 1st line of the definition. After the 1st line of the definition, lines always start with whitespace. So I fixed that problem (in my comment to you) with "^(?=\\w.+?:)". Unfortunately, using the EXACT same regex for the lookbehind, "^(?=\\w.+?:)|(?<=^\\w.+?:)" results in the error "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length". So I resorted to "(?<=^\\S+:)" for the lookbehind as a proof of concept. It works, but is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this using the `Scanner` API.

However, if you look at the source code for `Scanner`, you will see that there is a private `Matcher` object that is used to match the delimiter.  If you were willing to break open the `Scanner` abstraction (via nasty reflection) you could extract the information you need from the matcher ... if you examined it at the appropriate time.

If you were going to try this, my recommendation would be use the `Scanner` source code to create your own custom scanner class.  That would make your code immune to implementation changes to the standard `Scanner` class.

Make sure that you get the source code from OpenJDK, and satisfy the requirements of the "GPLv2" license on the file.

---

For what it is worth, I agree with what Sweeper said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833706/139985).  For this problem, capturing a token as a delimiter is the wrong way.

Treat the "term" as a first class token.  I would use `Scanner.next(Pattern)` to parse the token, where the `Pattern` matches a "term".

Comment: "There isn't a way to do this using the Scanner API." is the correct answer to the question as I asked it. But like you, I agree that Sweeper's answer gets me closer to a solution.